# ordering of writes between different pages in an mmaped file (on linux)

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap

What guarantees does linux paging system provide with respect to the ordering of writes to the filesystem between different pages?

In particular I am "serializing" some records into a file through mmap. Any single record/data item could possibly span multiple pages. Now let's say the machine crashes. Upon recovery how do I discard partially written records?

a) If I prepend each record with a length and end it with an "end" delimiter. Can I assume the presence of the "end" delimiter to indicate that the entire record was written? Even if the length and "end" can be on different pages? Does linux paging subsystem guarantee the order of writes of dirty pages?

b) What if I track the completion of writing a record through another file? Are there any "Happens Before" guarantees between files when writing to them through mmapped regions?

Comment: AFAIK, there are no guarantees at all until you call `fsync()`.

Comment: You may also need to call `msync()` first - not sure how the two interact.

Comment: @NateEldredge calling msync/fsync upon each record write isn't feasible for my use case due to the latency hit. I don't mind losing the last "few" records. All I'm after is if some record made it partially I need to discard it i.e. lost data is ok for my use case but corrupt data isn't.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, that's just too bad.  You may have to redesign your application to use a journal, or write and sync a clean copy periodically, or something like that.

Comment: @NateEldredge the mmapped file is the journal. We keep appending records to it and it's shared between multiple processes. Is there a fast way (comparable in speed to mmap) to append to a journal file and keep it shared between multiple processes (effectively tailing it)?

Comment: I would think of doing something like: when you are ready to flush (every 100 records or 30 seconds or whatever), you sync, write your end marker, and sync again.  But maybe someone with actual experience in, e.g. databases, will answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge even if i flush every 100 records, i have the same problem. how do i know the state of last 99 records? simply discarding the last 99 records on restart sounds silly. I still need some way to know which record is corrupt and which one isn't. While writing a checksum for the ending delimiter is possible I'm hoping to find a way I can rely on kernel guarantees.

Comment: You want guaranteed persistence without the latency of committing to storage?

Comment: @thatotherguy no i want guaranteed ordering i.e. if i write A, B, C to a file and I find C, I want to know that A and B correctly made it without worrying about fsync.